# Getting an intersection of two Redis sets in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis

I have a set looking like this (except that it has about 8000 items):

```
{"id":563244,"stock_id":693,"value":"9.17","span_minutes":1440,"symbol":"BCS"}
{"id":565527,"stock_id":10093,"value":"21.09","span_minutes":2880,"symbol":"GDXS"}
{"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","span_minutes":7200,"symbol":"NDAQ"}
{"id":565269,"stock_id":8883,"value":"127.60","span_minutes":5760,"symbol":"SAA"}
```

Now, what I want is to get entries with:

- value between 20 and 100
- span_minutes between 5000 and 8000

I can get these by first creating 2 new sorted sets and then using `zrangebyscore` to extract the entries I want:

```
ZADD values 9.17 '{"id":563244,"stock_id":693,"value":"9.17","symbol":"BCS"}'
ZADD values 21.09 {"id":565527,"stock_id":10093,"value":"21.09","span_minutes":2880,"symbol":"GDXS"}
ZADD values 91.52 {"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","span_minutes":7200,"symbol":"NDAQ"}
ZADD values 127.60 {"id":565269,"stock_id":8883,"value":"127.60","span_minutes":5760,"symbol":"SAA"}

ZADD spans 1440 '{"id":563244,"stock_id":693,"value":"9.17","symbol":"BCS"}'
ZADD spans 2880 {"id":565527,"stock_id":10093,"value":"21.09","span_minutes":2880,"symbol":"GDXS"}
ZADD spans 7200 {"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","span_minutes":7200,"symbol":"NDAQ"}
ZADD spans 5760 {"id":565269,"stock_id":8883,"value":"127.60","span_minutes":5760,"symbol":"SAA"}
```

Now, if I want to filter these sets to get the values I want, I can do this:

```
$value_range = Redis::zrangebyscore('values',20,100);
$span_range = Redis::zrangebyscore('spans',5000,8000);
```

These return, respectively:

```
1) {"id":565527,"stock_id":10093,"value":"21.09","span_minutes":2880,"symbol":"GDXS"}
2) {"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","span_minutes":7200,"symbol":"NDAQ"}
```

and

```
1) {"id":565269,"stock_id":8883,"value":"127.60","span_minutes":5760,"symbol":"SAA"}
2) {"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","span_minutes":7200,"symbol":"NDAQ"}
```

Now what I need is a way to combine these two sets. From what I can see in the Redis docs, I should be able to use [zinterstore](https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) for this purpose, but I don't understand the syntax and whatever I try keeps either throwing an error or returning the integer 0. For example:

`Redis::zinterstore('intersection', 2, $value_range, $span_range);` returns an error.

`$intereseciton = Redis::zinterstore(2, $value_range, $span_range);` returns 0.

What I should be getting is:

```
1) {"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","span_minutes":7200,"symbol":"NDAQ"}
```

because it's the only element of the original set that matches both of my conditions.

Maybe I have the wrong syntax, or the wrong approach altogether. How do I effectively get an intersection of the two sorted sets?

Comment: You have to do the intersection on the client side.

Comment: @for_stack Why? Isn't that what the interstore command is for? To return the entries that appear in both sets?

Comment: Because the result of `zrangebyscore` is on the client side, NOT stored in Redis. `zinterstore` can only do intersection of sets stored in Redis.

Comment: @for_stack Gotcha. So do you know another approach for accomplishing my goal completely in Redis or do I have to work on the client?

Comment: If you insist on intersecting on the server side, you can write a Lua script to do the job. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to do the intersection on the client side. Otherwise, you have to write a Lua script to do the job:

```
--inter.lua
local value_key = KEYS[1]
local span_key = KEYS[2]
local value_min = ARGV[1]
local value_max = ARGV[2]
local span_min = ARGV[3]
local span_max = ARGV[4]

local value_range = redis.call("zrangebyscore", value_key, value_min, value_max)
local span_range = redis.call("zrangebyscore", span_key, span_min, span_max)

-- do intersection
local value_set = {}
for _, item in ipairs(value_range) do
    value_set[item] = true
end

local result = {}
for _, item in ipairs(span_range) do
    if value_set[item] ~= nil then table.insert(result, item) end
end

return result
```

Run it like this: `redis-cli --eval inter.lua values spans , 20 100 5000 8000`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try both options and see what works better.